# Filter inner ng-repeat based on index of outer ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am trying to get the index of parent ng-repeat and in inner ng-repeat filter the data based of that.
Trying to use the below code but it is not working.

```
<div class="boxStyle" ng-repeat="priorityItem in priorityBox" data-tasktype= '{{$index+1}}' ui-drop-listener='dropListener' data-model='someArrays' > {{priorityItem.name}}
    <div ui-draggable ng-repeat="item in someArrays  | filter: {tasktype: "+ '{{$parent.$index}}' +" | orderBy: 'priority'" data-index='{{$index}}' data-taskid='{{item.taskid}}' data-priority='{{item.priority}}' class='btn btn-info btn-block'>{{item.name}}
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/kx7HEUtVJEavigxTzj3P?p=preview) is a plunker that does the job. It is not pretty because it duplicates the $index in order to make it easily accessible from the inner ng-repeat.
I would introduce a new custom filter to do the job.
This is the line that introduces a new variable which stores the parent index:

```
<div ng-init="parentIndex = $index"></div>
```

Good luck.